# How to add a column checkbox in a datagriview with data of csv file using c#

Tags: c#, csv, checkbox, datagridview

I want to add a new column with checkbox, my data is from a csv file and showed it in a datagridview with this code:

```
DataTable dtDataSource = new DataTable();
string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(\data.csv);

if (fileContent.Count() > 0)
{
    //Create data table columns
    dtDataSource.Columns.Add("ID);
    dtDataSource.Columns.Add("Data 1");
    dtDataSource.Columns.Add("Data 2");
    dtDataSource.Columns.Add("Status");

    //Add row data dynamically
    for (int i = 1; i < fileContent.Count(); i++)
    {
        string[] rowData = fileContent[i].Split(',');
        dtDataSource.Rows.Add(rowData);
    }
    if (dtDataSource != null)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtDataSource;
    }
}
```

But also I need to validate if checkbox is checked, the column ¨Status¨, their value must be changed by 1 or if is it unchecked the value must be 0 in every row of datagridview.

Example:

```
ID,Data1,Data2,Status,checkbox
1,aaa,bbb,0,✓
2,ccc,ddd,1,(unchecked)
3,eee,fff,1,(unchecked)
```

When you click the save button, the csv file should looks like this:

```
ID,Data1,Data2,Status
1,aaa,bbb,1
2,ccc,ddd,0
3,eee,fff,0
```

What I should do? Any ideas? CSV file is a little difficult for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this, thanks anyway..

This is the code:

```
string id;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)   {
        String path = "\\registros.csv";

        List<String> lines = new List<String>();

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    id = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                    if (line.Contains(","))
                    {

                        String[] split = line.Split(',');

                        if (split[1].Equals(id) && (bool)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue == true)
                        {

                            split[10] = "" + 1;
                            line = String.Join(",", split);

                        }

                        if (split[1].Equals(id) && (bool)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue == false) 
                        {

                            split[10] = "" + 0;
                            line = String.Join(",", split);

                        }

                    }
                    lines.Add(line);
                }

            }

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false))
            {
                foreach (String line in lines)
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
```